# Unable to extract postfixes using regular expression in R

Tags: r, regex

I am working on Single Cell RNA, and trying to demultiplex RAW count matrix. I am following [this](https://www.biomage.net/blog/how-to-demultiplex-an-rds-object-and-convert-it-to-10x-files). In this tutorial, the barcode is in this format:
`"BIOKEY_33_Pre_AAACCTGAGAGACTTA-1"`. Where `BIOKEY13_Pre` is the prefix and `AAACCTGCAACAACCT-1` is the sequence of bases. The prefixes are sample names, so they will be used to demultiplex the data.

Using this regular expression, I can extract the prefixes.
`data.pfx <- gsub("(.+)_[A-Z]+-1$", "\\1", colnames(data.count), perl=TRUE)`.

The problem is, in my data, the barcode is in this format:
`AAACCTGAGAAACCGC_LN_05` where the sequence is first, and the sample name is last. I need to extract postfixes. If I run the above regular expression on my data, I get the following output:

```
data.pfx <- gsub("(.+)_[A-Z]+-1$", "\\1", colnames(data.count), perl=TRUE)
sample.names <- unique(data.pfx)
head(sample.names)
"AAACCTGAGAAACCGC_LN_05" 
"AAACCTGAGAAACGCC_NS_13"
"AAACCTGAGCAATATG_LUNG_N34"

The desired output:
"LN_05"
"NS_13"
"LUNG_N34"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
sub(".*_([A-Z]+_[0-9A-Z]+)$", "\\1", sample.names)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HyGSe1/2).

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `_` - an underscore
- `([A-Z]+_[0-9A-Z]+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more uppercase ASCII letters, `_` and one or more  uppercase ASCII letters o digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Some barcode are in this format `AAACCTGAGCGACGTA_LUNG_T06` and this regular expression missed the postfix `LUNG_T06`

Comment: @RizwanAhmad Updated the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A bit easier by just removing all leading capital letters up to and including the first underscore

```
sample.names <- c("AAACCTGAGAAACCGC_LN_05" ,
                  "AAACCTGAGAAACGCC_NS_13")
sub("^[A-Z]+_", "", sample.names)
#> [1] "LN_05" "NS_13"
```